# spring why mocked method throws exception when optional exists

Tags: spring, testing, exception, mocking

i have endpoint like this:

```
@PostMapping("/departure")
public ResponseEntity<String> departure(@RequestBody CarAtGateModel carAtGateModel) throws UnidentifiedCarException {
    CarAndParkingEntity carAndParkingEntity = carsAndParkingsRepository.findByIdCar(
            carAtGateModel.getCarEntity().getIdCar()).orElseThrow(() -> new UnidentifiedCarException());

    carAndParkingEntity.setIdParking("-1");
    carsAndParkingsRepository.flush();
    return new ResponseEntity<>(responsesMessages.gateUp(), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

and next i wanted to do some tests with mocks like:

```
@Test
public void departureWorksWhenCarOnDepartureIsRecognized() {
    //given
    carsAndParkingsRepository = mock(CarsAndParkingsRepository.class);
    CarAndParkingEntity carAndParkingEntity = new CarAndParkingEntity();
    
    CarAtGateModel carAtGateModel =  new CarAtGateModel();
    CarEntity carEntity = new CarEntity();
    carEntity.setIdCar("-1");
    carEntity.setProducer("a");
    carEntity.setModel("b");
    carEntity.setWidth(1.6);
    carEntity.setPowerType(PowerType.PB);
    carAtGateModel.setCarEntity(carEntity);
    carAtGateModel.setParkingId("parkingId");

    //when
    when(carsAndParkingsRepository.findByIdCar(carEntity.getIdCar())).thenReturn(Optional.of(carAndParkingEntity));
    HttpEntity<CarAtGateModel> request = new HttpEntity<>(carAtGateModel);
    ResponseEntity<String> response = testRestTemplate.postForEntity("/departure", request, String.class);

    //then
    assertEquals(200, response.getStatusCodeValue());
}
```

Mocking repository for return optional works correctly, it returns `carAndParkingEntity`.
But test doesn't pass becouse it throws `UnidentifiedCarException` and I can't understand why I'm getting exception when `carsAndParkingsRepository.findByIdCar(carEntity.getIdCar())` returns optional, so it should exist...

Comment: You mocked the repository within the test method, but how is it getting injected into your controller? This is just a guess since we can't see the entire test class setup, but you may need to declare the repository as a member variable of the test class with `@Mock` or `@MockBean` annotation and add `@InjectMocks` to the controller.

Comment: I have public CarsAndParkingsRepository carsAndParkingsRepository; and in setUp i added carsAndParkingsRepository = mock(CarsAndParkingsRepository.class);

Answer (score 1):

You are providing lack of code to indentify problem correctly. From what i see, your mocked repository is nowhere injected into the controller. So you can not expect repository in controller to behave in a way you declared in your test.

Here is an example of how to test web layer in Spring https://spring.io/guides/gs/testing-web/

Tip: you shouldn't use repository nor business logic in your web layer. It is just terrible practice. Separate all logic into separate layer and mock that instead. Then you can make separate unit tests just for your logic. Testing your web layer shouldn't include testing of your repository access or business logic